# how to change response type in _dio.fetch when using dio/retrofit?

Tags: flutter, retrofit, flutter-dependencies, dio, flutter-plugin

I use dio, retrofit to manage api connections.
Codes related to annotations and build_runner are generated.

My problem:
I receive a list of data in the response.
The code that is generated is different from the code that I need.
There is a section in the generated code that contains this text.

```
final _result = await _dio.fetch<Map<String, dynamic>>(_setStreamType<
```

And the code I need is like this.

```
final _result = await _dio.fetch<List<dynamic>>(_setStreamType<
```

- When i manually edit  *Map<String, dynamic>*  to  *List<‍dynamic>*  my code working fine And I need something like annotion or etc doing automatically will be resolved this problem .

This is my code snippet:

```
@RestApi(baseUrl: BuildConfig.SERVER)
abstract class GetApiService {
  factory GetApiService(Dio dio,{String baseUrl}) = _GetApiService;
  @GET(MainApi.baseData)
  @FormUrlEncoded()
  Future<HttpResponse<ResponseList>> getDashboardHomeResponse();
}
```

**Sample my response received:**

```
 [
    {
          'key1':'value1',
          'key2':'value2',
          'key3':'value3'
    }
 ]
```

Comment: can you add sample of you response you get?

Comment: Sample my response received :
 [
    {
          'key1':'value1',
          'key2':'value2',
          'key3':'value3'
    }
 ]

Comment: where the problem is? you said you need a List<dynamic> and you get it.

Comment: my response always ok . generated code by build_runner/retrofit not match by List<dynamic> ... ok dude !  ... always generated code for Map<String, dynamic> ... when manually edit to List<dynamic> my code working fine ... i need something  like annotion or etc doing automatically will be resolved this problem  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resoleve problem.

The type of data that you give to the http response must be of the List type.
so that your dio response is *List<‌‍dynamic>*.

otherwise , the response generator will return a *Map<String, dynamic>* type.

My mistake was in passing the data type to **HttpResponse**.

My class model passing to  HttpResponse  has a **list type variable** , but I have to create the class model individually.

This is my edited code snippet:

```
@RestApi(baseUrl: BuildConfig.SERVER)
abstract class GetApiService {
  factory GetApiService(Dio dio,{String baseUrl}) = _GetApiService;
  @GET(MainApi.baseData)
  @FormUrlEncoded()
  Future<HttpResponse<List<ResponseItem>>> getDashboardHomeResponse(); ///Pay attention to the type , Type is List!
}
```